# Find which target-https-proxies are using specific ssl-certificate on Google Cloud from Golang code or gcloud

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Let's assume I do have access only to some Google Cloud projects. The certificate is global. How can I verify if ssl-certificate is not in use? Certificate can be used in other projects where I do not have access to.

Is the only one option `gcloud compute ssl-certificates delete certificate_name`?

> SSL certificates can only be deleted when no other resources (for example, target HTTPS proxies) refer to them.

Okay, I can try to delete it, but is there no way to know what Target HTTPS Proxy using it?

Is there any field that could help from official docs https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/targetHttpsProxies/setSslCertificates ?

---

I need to know if it is possible to do using Golang.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Cloud Asset API, you could list all Target HTTPS Proxies using a specific ssl certificate within the filter option. For example, here we list all Target HTTPS Proxies in an organisation using a specific certificate:

```
gcloud asset list --organization='<MY ORGANIZATION ID>' \
  --billing-project='<MY BILLING PROJECT ID>' \
  --snapshot-time=$NOW \
  --filter="resource.data.sslCertificates:<MY SSL CERTIFICATE SELF LINK>" \
  --asset-types='compute.googleapis.com/TargetHttpsProxy' \
  --content-type='resource'
```

I am not familiar with go, but you can probably translate this command in go language with the client library.